# How can I calculate Shortest Path through Neo4j in my Spring Boot through localhost and Docker?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, neo4j

I have a problem about calculating the shortest path through Neo4j in my Spring Boot example.

After adding some cities with its route, I want to calculate their shortest path in terms of their connection and their duration. However, these two methods which defined in ShortestPathController cannot work.

Here are the **issues** shown below.

Edited

**1 )** I cannot run all **test** methods in **AppApplicationTests.java**

```
org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.AuthenticationException: The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure.
```

**2 )** I have no idea as I cannot run all test methods what if there are many cities and its route like this resource ([Link](https://vladbatushkov.medium.com/one-month-graph-challenge-hero-city-cc4ffa51bb1b))

How can I fix it?

Here is my GitHub repository : [Project Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/SpringBootNeo4jShortestPath)

Here is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'

services:
  neo4j-db:
    image: neo4j:4.3
    container_name: app-neo4j-db
    ports:
      - 7474:7474
      - 7687:7687
    volumes:
      - $HOME/neo4j/data:/data
      - $HOME/neo4j/logs:/logs
      - $HOME/neo4j/import:/import
      - $HOME/neo4j/plugins:/plugins
    environment:
      NEO4J_AUTH: "neo4j/123456"
      NEO4JLABS_PLUGINS: '["apoc"]'
      NEO4J_dbms_security_procedures_unrestricted: apoc.\\\*,gds.\\\*
      dbms_connector_bolt_listen__address: neo4j-db:7687
      dbms_connector_bolt_advertised__address: neo4j-db:7687
    healthcheck:
      test: cypher-shell --username neo4j --password 123456 'MATCH (n) RETURN COUNT(n);' # Checks if neo4j server is up and running
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5

  app:
    image: 'springbootneo4jshortestpath:latest'
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: SpringBootNeo4jShortestPath
    depends_on:
      neo4j-db:
        condition: service_healthy # Wait for neo4j to be ready
    links:
      - neo4j-db
    environment:
      NEO4J_URI: bolt://neo4j-db:7687
      NEO4J_USER: neo4j
      NEO4J_PASSWORD: 123456

volumes:
  app-neo4j-db:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part 1: This is *just* a warning. In most cases you would not be happy with unbound relationships because the paths can quickly grow in numbers and the server has to keep all possible combination in memory before you will get it.

Part 2: What @jose_bacoy says. Behind the link are informations about how to add APOC in Desktop, Server or Docker deployment. Test your query (or even a reduced version of it) in the shell/browser to ensure it is activated correctly.

Part 2 (again but different topic): You cannot return `PathValue` in a repository. If you want to use the Java driver's type, please use SDN's `Neo4jClient` for interaction. [SDN documentation / Neo4jClient](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#neo4j-client)

(Edit and added)
Docker compose:
I could not make it work to provide an array with the other syntax, so basically this will auto-load the plugin on container start.
You can check if the APOC library is available via `CALL dbms.procedures()` in the shell or browser.
This is what you should do **first**.

```
environment:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
      - NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/secret                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
      - NEO4JLABS_PLUGINS=["apoc"]
```

Comment: Question 1 : How can I fix my issue ? Question 2 : the link should be mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.neo4j.procedure/apoc/4.4.0.5. Is it right? How can I add it into my docker-compose.yml After adding this dependency and updating maven, I test it again but the issue cannot disappear.

Comment: 1. If you want to get all paths, there is nothing to worry about.
2. If you are using the latest version (4.4.) of the database yes. But looking at the docker compose file, you do not have to download anything manually but define the env. variable `NEO4JLABS_PLUGINS:\[\"apoc\"\]` (I don't know how to properly escape this for compose) as it as written in the link docs in the other answer.

Comment: Updated my answer with a compose info. You were NOT using the APOC plugin or at least never verified it's there.

Comment: correct, see: _Part 2 (again but different topic)_ in my previous answer.

Comment: Taking a conceptual step back: From what I see in the repository, there is no method that creates a Route between two cities. It's always `(:City)-[ROUTES]->(:Route)` but always with a new `Route` node. So there should be either a directed `(:City)-[ROUTES]->(:Route)-[:DESTINATION]->(:City)` or if the route is valid for both directions (what I would say it is not(?)) `(:City)-[ROUTES]->(:Route)<-[:ROUTES]->(:City)`.
Side note: there is community.neo4j.com where I think those evolving discussion are better suited.

Comment: Updated my repo: https://github.com/meistermeier/SpringBootNeo4jShortestPath Now the domain model looks like `City->Route->City` do please the shortestPath algorithm. Also please have a look at the `ApplicationWebTests`. They should explain how the updated `saveRoute` method should work.

Comment: Alright, there is now another commit with changes in the service incl. web test for Dijkstra. The main idea is that you iterate over the `Routes` and sum up the `duration` of each.

Comment: I have no idea right now what the problem might be. Also I think updating the question all the time is not the right approach on SO to do. In the long run question and answer differs and nobody will benefit. Use the forums and try to stick with one problem at a time (per topic).

Comment: I cannot run any test of AppApplicationTests. Is it possible to look through it

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that APOC library is installed in your Neo4j server. Please follow this installation procedure.

```
 https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.0/installation/#neo4j-server
```

Then update your conf file to whitelist that function.